# How to disable chips in android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I've chip group that I want to disable when some operation happen.

Currently my code look like this:

```
           R.id.all -> {
                    chipGroup.clearCheck()
                    chipGroup.isClickable = false
                    selectedCategory = null
                }
```

It does clear all the checks, but I still can click and select chips.

How can I prevent all the chips from being clicked?

Comment: Is there something like `chipGroup.enabled = false`?

Comment: Just use `chipGroup.isEnabled = false`

Comment: It's very weird, but it is still let me click on the chips  even with ```isEnabled = false```

Comment: What about setting `isEnabled = false` to all chips within your chipGroup?

Comment: I probably could but it's a huge code duplication,,I'm sure there is a way to disable all the chips at once

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This Kotlin Extension Function allows you to enable/disable all Chips within the Chip Group:

```
    fun ChipGroup.setChildrenEnabled(enable: Boolean) {
        children.forEach { it.isEnabled = enable }
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
    chipGroup.setChildrenEnabled(false)
```

Comment: what is children? should it be imported? android studio suggests: 

`import androidx.core.view.children` or  `import kotlinx.coroutines.NonCancellable.children`

Comment: @gccallie use `androidx.core.view.children`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setChipEnable(boolean status) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chipGrp.getChildCount(); i++) {
        chipGrp.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(status);
    }
}

setChipEnable(false);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers.